# How to get value of a key inside each array of object where array can be dynamic and multilevel

Tags: laravel, collections

I need all the ids inside the `recursive_sub` and it can be inside one another and can be multilevel

```
{
"id": 1,
"parent_id": null,
"name": "Ch 1",
"recursive_sub": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "name": "T 1",
        "recursive_sub": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "parent_id": 3,
                "name": "L100",
                "recursive_sub": [
                    {
                        "id": 26,
                        "parent_id": 4,
                        "name": "Line 23",
                        "recursive_sub": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "parent_id": 3,
                "name": "L2",
                "recursive_sub": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "name": "T 2",
        "recursive_sub": []
    }
]}
```

Looping through the array is not a solution because it has limitation. Here `recursive_sub` can have many other `recursive_sub` insid one another

Is there any way in Laravel collection to collect all the `id` inside each `recursive array`

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function
First convert your string json to php associative array:

```php
$stringData = '{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "Ch 1",
    "recursive_sub": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "name": "T 1",
            "recursive_sub": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "L100",
                    "recursive_sub": [
                        {
                            "id": 26,
                            "parent_id": 4,
                            "name": "Line 23",
                            "recursive_sub": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "L2",
                    "recursive_sub": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "name": "T 2",
            "recursive_sub": []
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($stringData, true);
```

Then define your recursive (anonymous) function:

```php
$getIds = function ($node, $accumulator = []) use (&$getIds) {
    return array_reduce($node, function ($carry, $item) use ($getIds) {
        $carry[] = $item['id'];
        return $item['recursive_sub'] ? $getIds($item['recursive_sub'], $carry) : $carry;
    }, $accumulator);
};
```

Finally call it:

```php
$ids = $getIds([$data]);
print_r($ids);
```